# loading some typescript modules with requireJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, js-amd

I have a problem with the connection of some typescript classes using RequireJs.
In .ts files I use the modules syntax and AMD modules. And my main file is GameLoader.ts which returns a instance of the game. There for example I'm creaiting World instance:

```
import World = require('Resources/Scripts/Game/Entities/Game/World');
...
var world = new World(json.world.level, json.world.size, json.world.passMap);
```

and it works fine - World really required function

But at the same the same file (GameLoader.ts):

```
import Camera = require('Resources/Scripts/Game/Presentation/Camera/Camera');
...
var camera = new Camera();
```

**Camera is empty object (instead of the function)** *Uncaught TypeError: Camera is not a function*
The file is loaded, but the debugger showed that its contents are not used - breakpoint within the function define doesn't work. But in World breakpoint is triggered prior to loading the main program.

Finding fault I tried to remove all things from Camera.ts.
After removal of I called empty Camera in the same manner from another file (temp.ts):

```
import c = require('Resources/Scripts/Game/Presentation/Camera/Camera');
var cam = new c();
console.log(cam);
```

and it worked.

Ts-generated code by compiler (for Camera.js) in both cases looks the same.
To call compiled files used the same way - by call RequireJs API.

Perhaps the problem is cyclical references that point to a file GameLoader?
But my application built from classes that game (which instance exported from GameLoader) is used only in theirs instances.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Does Camera have a define function and does it return the correct object?

Comment: Yes. Camera.js starts with define function.
She returns ref on Camera function (class in TS). But for some reason in GameLoader it is just empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps the problem is cyclical references that point to a file GameLoader?

Probably. Give the dependency view in atom-typescript a go https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#dependency-view

Comment: I tried to setup atom and this plugin but he does not recognize import statement at all, even after setup tsconfig. So I prefer VS or VS Code. There all fine for me.
Now cyclical refs: Camera has import of CameraBehaviour which has import of GameLoader. It needs for reading level configuration for camera position correction. Is RequireJs can't handle it?

Comment: Yes, you can get an undefined on initial load http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

Answer (score 0):

I shot in my leg with RequireJs. Problem there that I tried to return **instance** from shared module. And every dependency tried to create new. So at first time - in my case - some modules missed on load other deps stage.